# Many-to-many - return only objects from symmetrical relationship

Tags: django, django-models, orm, many-to-many, django-orm

I have following code in `models.py`:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="from_person")
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="to_person")
```

And this field defined in `User` model:
`friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, through='Relationship')`

What I want is when I execute later in the view `request.user.friends.all()` to return only users which have symmetrical relationship with the logged-in user, because when I do this:
`Relationship.objects.filter(from_person__in=request.user.friends.all(), to_person=request.user)`
It returns `Relationship` objects of course, but I want to have the `User` ones like in the command above it.

The question is how to achieve that? I suppose that I have to make custom m2m manager and to somehow modify `get_queryset()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved it with this command:
`User.objects.filter(from_person__from_person__in=request.user.friends.all(), from_person__to_person=request.user)`